# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk: Environment variable cannot be removed - reverts to previous value

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We're running multiple ELB environments on the Puma with Ruby stack. We've recently reached the 4096 Bytes limit for environment variables. Therefore I tried to remove some legacy env variables in order to release some space for new environment variables.

However, it seems I am only able to update the value of the variables.
E.g. I can change `MY_SECRET=secret` to just `MY_SECRET=a`, which is then reflected on all instances. If I try to remove it completely, the value is then reverted to the previous one (`MY_SECRET=secret` - **not** `a`).

I tried to remove them via the web UI and also via the eb cli tool (`eb setenv MY_SECRET=`). Both claim to have finished successfully, but the environment variable is not removed. It behaves the same for different environment variables.

Has anybody an idea of why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well... I am also getting this exact issue. The old values must be stored somewhere, but the only place where it restores on the configuration UI is when applying a saved configuration, which I don't have nor using. It's also not consistent though. I have been able to remove variables using the AWS Console without issues for a distinct environment in the same account.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `eb setenv MY_SECRET=` did not yield any success, do you mean that it just errored out? If so, I recommend that you try `eb setenv 'MY_SECRET='`. In your unsuccessful attempt, the "=" was not handled by Bash (or whichever shell you are on) as you expected. I have been able to verify that my approach works.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried it, but sadly without success. 
Both update methods claim that they finished successfully, but the environment variable is not removed :/

Comment: In the events log (`eb events`), do you see a problem that is preventing the update or causing a rollback to a previous version of your application as you attempt to perform the update?

Comment: No, based on the events everything seems to be just fine: `Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.` and `Environment update completed successfully.`

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Posting about your problem on AWS forums might help. I recommend you do that.

Comment: Yes. I already did that, but got no answer yet ;) Seems I'll have to setup a new environment :/

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. The solution was to use AWS CLI, but not by using `--options-to-remove`. That yielded the same result as using `eb setenv` or the AWS Console UI directly. Instead set the value of the option to null, like:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment
  --environment-name <env_name>
  --option-settings
    Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment,OptionName=MY_SECRET,Value=null
```

This finally sorted out my problem and hope it sorts out anyone else's hitting this wall.